# error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the'obj' parameter in selecting the method for the'coordinates' function

Tags: r

I encountered a problem in R but don't know how to solve it. This is my code:

```
lixels2008 <- lixelize_lines(mtl_2008network, 150, mindist = 50)
```

The error message  as follows:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the'obj' parameter in selecting the method for 
the'coordinates' function: the parameter value means a different number 
of rows: 3, 4
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the 
first 50)`
```

The explanation of the lixelize_lines function(https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spNetwork/versions/0.1.1/topics/lixelize_lines)

`Mtl_2008network` contains all the links of the London road network, from the gkpg file. Its attribute values include length of link, start node of link, end node of link, link ID and others.
Anyone have any advice? Many thanks!